# Restored database from backup file apparently not "recognised" by SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database-restore

I have restored the Northwind database(https://northwinddatabase.codeplex.com/) from a backup file, I have successfully executed a trivial query, but, apparently there are some errors. This is the screenshot:

[image]

What is the problem?

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. This is more DBA-related, so try the DBA site.

Comment: I have just edited the tags. There is a stackoverflow bug. After clicking "Ask a question", the previous asked one was loaded, I had to delete the old subject and text, but forgot about the tags.

Comment: This is because your intellisense cache needs to be refreshed. Just hit ctrl+shift+r. Or you can use the menu. Edit -> Intellisense -> Refresh Local cache

Comment: @SeanLange: Does the compatibility level in the target database need to be a certain level as well? Something in the back of my mind says that when this feature came out I had a newer version of SSMS and an older database and intellisense didn't work. Since this is Northwind, changing the compatibility level is an option.

Comment: Not sure what impact compatibility has on intellisense to be honest. I would just set it to the latest level you have and it should be fine. Of course this isn't an actual error. It is just an issue with intellisense. Either update the cache or restart SSMS and it should be fine.